# Possible ODR-violations when using a constexpr variable in the definition of an inline function (in C++14)

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer

*(Note! This question particularly covers the state of C++14, before the introduction of inline variables in C++17)*

#### TLDR; Question

- What constitutes odr-use of a constexpr variable used in the definition of an inline function, such that multiple definitions of the function violates [basic.def.odr]/6?

(... likely [basic.def.odr]/3; but could this silently introduce UB in a program as soon as, say, the address of such a constexpr variable is taken in the context of the inline function's definition?)

TLDR example: does a program where `doMath()` defined as follows:

```
// some_math.h
#pragma once

// Forced by some guideline abhorring literals.
constexpr int kTwo{2};
inline int doMath(int arg) { return std::max(arg, kTwo); }
                                 // std::max(const int&, const int&)
```

have undefined behaviour as soon as `doMath()` is defined in two different translation units (say by inclusion of `some_math.h` and subsequent use of `doMath()`)?

#### Background

Consider the following example:

```
// constants.h
#pragma once
constexpr int kFoo{42};

// foo.h
#pragma once
#include "constants.h"
inline int foo(int arg) { return arg * kFoo; }  // #1: kFoo not odr-used

// a.cpp
#include "foo.h"
int a() { return foo(1); }  // foo odr-used

// b.cpp
#include "foo.h"
int b() { return foo(2); }  // foo odr-used
```

compiled for C++14, particularly before inline variables and thus before constexpr variables were implicitly inline.

The inline function `foo` (which has external linkage) is odr-used in both translation units (TU) associated with `a.cpp` and `b.cpp`, say `TU_a` and `TU_b`, and shall thus be defined in both of these TU's ([[basic.def.odr]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/basic.def.odr#4)).

[[basic.def.odr]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/basic.def.odr#6) covers the requirements for when such multiple definitions (different TU's) may appear, and particularly /6.1 and /6.2 is relevant in this context [**emphasis** mine]:

> There can be more than one definition of a [...] inline function with external linkage [...] in a program
> provided that each definition appears in a different translation unit,
> and provided the definitions satisfy the following requirements. Given
> such an entity named D defined in more than one translation unit, then
>
> - /6.1 each definition of D shall consist of the same sequence of tokens; and
> - /6.2 in each definition of D, corresponding names, looked up according to [basic.lookup], shall refer to an entity defined within
>   the definition of D, or shall refer to the same entity, after overload
>   resolution ([over.match]) and after matching of partial template
>   specialization ([temp.over]), **except that** a name can refer to a
>   non-volatile const object with internal or no linkage if the object
>   has the same literal type in all definitions of D, and the object is
>   initialized with a constant expression ([expr.const]), and **the object
>   is not odr-used**, and the object has the same value in all definitions
>   of D; and
> - ...
>
> **If the definitions of D do not satisfy these requirements, then the behavior is undefined.**

/6.1 is fulfilled.

/6.2 if fulfilled if `kFoo` in `foo`:

1. [OK] is const with internal linkage
2. [OK] is initialized with a constant expressions
3. [OK] is of same literal type over all definitions of `foo`
4. [OK] has the same value in all definitions of `foo`
5. [??] is not odr-used.

I interpret 5 as particularly "not odr-used **in the definition of `foo`**"; this could arguably have been clearer in the wording. However if `kFoo` *is* odr-used (at least in the definition of `foo`) I interpret it as opening up for odr-violations and subsequent undefined behavior, due to violation of [basic.def.odr]/6.

Afaict [[basic.def.odr]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/basic.def.odr#3) governs whether `kFoo` is odr-used or not,

> A variable x whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression ex is odr-used by ex unless applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion ([conv.lval]) to x yields a constant expression ([expr.const]) that does not invoke any non-trivial functions and, if x is an object, ex is an element of the set of potential results of an expression e, where either the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion ([conv.lval]) is applied to e, or e is a discarded-value expression (Clause [expr]). [...]

but I'm having a hard time to understand whether `kFoo` is considered as odr-used e.g. if its address is taken within the definition of `foo`, or e.g. whether if its address is taken outside of the definition of `foo` or not affects whether [basic.def.odr]/6.2 is fulfilled or not.

---

**Further details**

Particularly, consider if `foo` is defined as:

```
// #2
inline int foo(int arg) { 
    std::cout << "&kFoo in foo() = " << &kFoo << "\n";
    return arg * kFoo; 
}
```

and `a()` and `b()` are defined as:

```
int a() { 
    std::cout << "TU_a, &kFoo = " << &kFoo << "\n";
    return foo(1); 
}

int b() { 
    std::cout << "TU_b, &kFoo = " << &kFoo << "\n";
    return foo(2); 
}
```

then running a program which calls `a()` and `b()` in sequence produces:

```
TU_a, &kFoo    = 0x401db8
&kFoo in foo() = 0x401db8  // <-- foo() in TU_a: 
                           //     &kFoo from TU_a

TU_b, &kFoo    = 0x401dbc
&kFoo in foo() = 0x401db8  // <-- foo() in TU_b: 
                           // !!! &kFoo from TU_a
```

namely the address of the TU-local `kFoo` when accessed from the different `a()` and `b()` functions, but pointing to the same `kFoo` address when accessed from `foo()`.

[DEMO](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RY7wLBuh3R5z10yh).

Does this program (with `foo` and `a`/`b` defined as per this section) have undefined behaviour?

A real life example would be where these constexpr variables represent mathematical constants, and where they are used, from within the definition of an inline function, as arguments to utility math functions such as `std::max()`, which takes its arguments by reference.

Comment: `arg * kFoo` doesn't use adress of `kFoo`, so it should be fine. returning `std::max(arg, kFoo);` would odr-use `kFoo` (`std::max` takes its argument by const reference)

Comment: Tangent: constexpr variables are only implicitly inline if they are static member variables.

Comment: @Jarod42 I just updated with a TLDR `std::max` example: this example (which I see not too uncommonly in C++14 code bases, prior to C++17's `constexpr` `std::max` and so on) is then UB as soon as the function is defined in more than one translation unit? Particularly, the AUTOSAR guidelines for use of C++14 in safety critical systems enforce the following (required) rule, _"A5-1-1: Literal values shall not be used apart from type initialization, otherwise symbolic names shall be used instead."_, which typically results in various constants such as `constexpr int kTwo{2};` when adhered to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the OP's example with `std::max`, an ODR violation does indeed occur, and the program is ill-formed NDR. To avoid this issue, you might consider one of the following fixes:

- give the `doMath` function internal linkage, or
- move the declaration of `kTwo` inside `doMath`

A variable that is used by an expression is considered to be odr-used unless there is a certain kind of simple proof that the reference to the variable can be replaced by the compile-time constant value of the variable without changing the result of the expression. If such a simple proof exists, then the standard requires the compiler perform such a replacement; consequently the variable is not odr-used (in particular, it does not require a definition, and the issue described by the OP would be avoided because *none* of the translation units in which `doMath` is defined would actually reference a definition of `kTwo`). If the expression is too complicated, however, then all bets are off. The compiler might *still* replace the variable with its value, in which case the program may work as you expect; or the program may exhibit bugs or crash. That's the reality with IFNDR programs.

The case where the variable is immediately passed by reference to a function, with the reference binding directly, is one common case where the variable is used in a way that is too complicated and the compiler is not required to determine whether or not it may be replaced by its compile-time constant value. This is because doing so would necessarily require inspecting the definition of the function (such as `std::max<int>` in this example).

You can "help" the compiler by writing `int(kTwo)` and using that as the argument to `std::max` as opposed to `kTwo` itself; this prevents an odr-use since the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is now immediately applied prior to calling the function. I don't think this is a great solution (I recommend one of the two solutions that I previously mentioned) but it has its uses (GoogleTest uses this in order to avoid introducing odr-uses in statements like `EXPECT_EQ(2, kTwo)`).

If you want to know more about how to understand the precise definition of odr-use, involving "potential results of an expression *e*...", that would be best addressed with a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

> Does a program where doMath() defined as follows: [...] have undefined behaviour as soon as `doMath()` is defined in two different translation units (say by inclusion of `some_math.h` and subsequent use of `doMath()`)?

Yes; this particular issue was highlighted in [LWG2888](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2888) and [LWG2889](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2889) which were both resolved for C++17 by [P0607R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0607r0.html) (*Inline Variables for the Standard Library*) [**emphasis** mine]:

> #### 2888. Variables of library tag types need to be inline variables
>
> [...]
>
> The variables of library tag types need to be inline variables.
> **Otherwise, using them in inline functions in multiple translation
> units is an ODR violation**.
>
> Proposed change: Make piecewise_construct, allocator_arg, nullopt,
> (the in_place_tags after they are made regular tags), defer_lock,
> try_to_lock and adopt_lock inline.
>
> [...]
>
> [2017-03-12, post-Kona] Resolved by p0607r0.
>
> #### 2889. Mark constexpr global variables as inline
>
> The C++ standard library provides many constexpr global variables.
> These **all create the risk of ODR violations for innocent user code.**
> This is especially bad for the new ExecutionPolicy algorithms, since
> their constants are always passed by reference, so any use of those
> algorithms from an inline function results in an ODR violation.
>
> This can be avoided by marking the globals as inline.
>
> Proposed change: Add inline specifier to: bind placeholders _1, _2,
> ..., nullopt, piecewise_construct, allocator_arg, ignore, seq, par,
> par_unseq in
>
> [...]
>
> [2017-03-12, post-Kona] Resolved by p0607r0.

Thus, in C++14, prior to `inline` variables, this risk is present both for your own global variables as well as library ones.